# How to get all the p tags from the soup object

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was scraping reviews of Kickstarter. I was able to get the name of the reviewer and the 1st `p` tag that contains the review. But for some reviews there's additional `p` tags that I want to scrape. How to do that.

Here is the code I've written.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\silvi\projects\selenium_basics\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/kickstarter.com'
# driver.get(url)

soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for review in soup.select('div .url-reviews .review'):
    name = review.a.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    customer_review = review.find('p').text
    print(name)
    print(customer_review)
    print()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What did you do to try and get the other `p` tags?

Comment: I tried to use findAll but that didn't work. And if I use  customer_review = review.find('div').text  I get my desired results but also the additional information like comment, thank you, respond as company. I want to avoid scraping those and scrape only the `p` tags.

Comment: If you had posted how you tried to use `findall`, someone might have been able to point out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `review.find_all('p')`, then use a list comprehension to get the text out of all of them, skipping the first as you already have that in `customer_review`

```py
for review in soup.select('div .url-reviews .review'):
    name = review.a.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    customer_review = review.find('p').text
    other_ps = [p.text for p in review.find_all('p')[1:]]
    
    print(name)
    print(customer_review)
    print(other_ps)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\silvi\projects\selenium_basics\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/kickstarter.com'
# driver.get(url)

soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
divs=soup.findAll('div',{"class": ["url-reviews","review"]})
for review in divs:
    name = review.a.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    print(name)
    customer_review = review.find_all('p')
    print("========================")
    for p in customer_review:
        print(p.text)
        print(" - - - -")
driver.quit()
```

use customer_review = review.find_all('p') and with a for print its elements text